# Narrowing from literal doesn't cause warning

Tags: c++, initialization, language-lawyer, list-initialization, narrowing

`int a = 0; short b{a}; short c{0};`

The compiler gives a waring for `short b{a}`. I can understand this, because `int` is narrowed to `short`.

However, it doesn't give a warning to `short c{0}`, which is weird to me.  My remember for literal integers, the type of `0` should at least be `int`.  So narrowing from `int` to `short` is happening here. Why doesn't the compiler give a warning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `short c{0};`, [narrowing conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization#Narrowing_conversions) doesn't occur. Because `0` is a constant expression and can be stored exactly in a `short`.

(emphasis mine)

> list-initialization limits the allowed implicit conversions by prohibiting the following:
>
> - ...
> - conversion from integer or unscoped enumeration type to integer type that cannot represent all values of the original, **except where source is a constant expression whose value can be stored exactly in the target type**

Relevant explanations and examples from the standard, [$8.6.4/7 List-initialization
[dcl.init.list]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#7):

(emphasis mine)

> A narrowing conversion is an implicit conversion
>
> - ...
> - from an integer type or unscoped enumeration type to an integer type that cannot represent all the values of the original type, **except
>     where the source is a constant expression whose value after integral
>     promotions will fit into the target type**.
>
> [ Note: As indicated above, such conversions are not allowed at the
>   top level in list-initializations. — end note ] [ Example:
>
> ```
> // ...
> const int z = 99;
> // ...
> char c4{z};               // OK: no narrowing needed
> unsigned char uc1 = {5};  // OK: no narrowing needed
> // ...
> float f2 { 7 };           // OK: 7 can be exactly represented as a float
> // ...
> ```
>
> — end example ]

Comment: do you think the "after integral promotions"  unecessary?

Comment: @FunkyBaby I think it just means technically, the constant would be integral promoted at first, then the promoted value will be checked whether it could fit into the target type.